# AWS amplify cognito show Home Screen after signing user up ios

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swiftui, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to write an iOS app with swiftui that uses amplify and aws cognito to sign users up and navigate to the home/session screen after the user has signed up with a username/password/phone/email and confirmed a code with an email. I'm currently having a problem where after signing up the user, my iOS app navigates back to the login screen as it can't detect that there is a current user using the Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() function call.
Here is the code that contains this logic:

```
//
//  TheClubMobileApp.swift
//  TheClubMobile
//
//  Created by Hari S on 12/27/20.
//

import SwiftUI
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins

@main
struct TheClubMobileApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var sessionManager = SessionManager()
    init(){
        configureAmplify()
        sessionManager.getCurrentAuthUser()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch sessionManager.authState {
                
                case .login:
                    LoginView()
                        .environmentObject(sessionManager)
                    
                case .signUp:
                    SignUpView()
                        .environmentObject(sessionManager)
                    
                case .confirmCode(let username):
                    ConfirmationView(username: username)
                        .environmentObject(sessionManager)
                    
                case .session(let user ):
                    SessionView(user: user)
                        .environmentObject(sessionManager)
                
            }
        }
    }
    func configureAmplify(){
        do{
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("Amplify configured successfully")
        } catch {
            print("failed to configure Amplify ")
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Amplify

enum AuthState {
    case signUp
    case login
    case confirmCode(username: String)
    case session(user: AuthUser)
}
final class SessionManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var authState: AuthState = .login
    
    func getCurrentAuthUser() {
        if let user = Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() {
            authState = .session(user: user)
        } else {
            authState = .login
        }
    }
    
    func showSignUp() {
        authState = .signUp
    }
    
    func showLogin() {
        authState = .login
    }
   
    
    func signUp(username: String, email: String, phoneNumber: String, password: String){
        let attributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email), AuthUserAttribute(.phoneNumber, value: phoneNumber)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: attributes)
        
        _ = Amplify.Auth.signUp(
            username: username,
            password: password,
            options: options
        ) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let signUpResult):
                    print("Sign up result: ", signUpResult)
                    
                    switch signUpResult.nextStep {
                    case .done:
                        print("Finished Sign Up")
                    case .confirmUser(let details, _):
                        print(details ?? "no details")
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self?.authState = .confirmCode(username: username)
                        }
                  
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Sign up error: ", error)
            
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func confirm(username: String, code: String){
        _ = Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
            for: username,
            confirmationCode: code
        ) { [weak self] result in
            
            switch result {
                case .success(let confirmResult):
                    print(confirmResult)
                    if confirmResult.isSignupComplete {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self?.getCurrentAuthUser()
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("failed to confirm code: ", error)
            }
            
        }
    }
    func login(username: String, password: String) {
        _ = Amplify.Auth.signIn(
            username: username,
            password: password
        ) { [weak self] result in
            
            switch result {
                case .success(let signInResult):
                    print(signInResult)
                    
                    if signInResult.isSignedIn {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self?.getCurrentAuthUser()
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Login error: ", error)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    func signOut() {
        _ = Amplify.Auth.signOut(
        ) { [weak self] result in
            
            switch result {
                case .success:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.getCurrentAuthUser()
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Login error: ", error)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

After the user successfully confirms with a code with the func confirm, I expect the iOS app to navigate to the session view using the getCurrentAuthUser() as there should be a new user. However, it goes into the else case and displays my login view. It works correctly on the backend as I can see the user being signed up and I can login with the same credentials and then navigate to the session view but I can't seem to figure out how to navigate to the session view right after signing up. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem on my side. AWS looks crap compared with Firebase. Needs to spend  ages to implement users onboarding functionality.

Comment: Did you found solution?